# DNN List multiple documents on page

Tags: dotnetnuke, documents

I am developing an intranet using DotNetNuke and would like know if anyone has come across a module for listing many files stored in a website folder.

I have many pages which need to list a lot of reference documents, and am happy with DNN's ability to upload them into the file manager, but am coming unstuck with regard to adding each file to the 'Documents' module one by one for each page on the site.

I have done heaps of searching on this and was wondering if anyone had come across the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed. Check out Ventrian's [file links module](http://www.ventrian.com/Products/Modules/FileLinks.aspx)

Use the core DNN file component to make directories and upload files into those directories. Then use Ventrian File Links to drop that module onto a page on your DNN site. You can then tell it what directory to show files for and it will list them nicely on the site for you.

It's very slick. Ventrian is a yearly fee, but their Articles module and Photo Gallery module are also amazing and I use them in majority of my projects.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for! 

It would be nice to find a free version of this, but absolutely spot on.

Comment: There is a free alternative available at http://www.iowacomputergurus.com/free-products/dotnetnuke-modules/simple-file-list.aspx

Comment: The guys at Iowa Computer Gurus have a whole heap of free DotNetNuke modules on that site notAndy, very helpful guys. I ended up going with them for the file management.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Document Library module in the commercial editions of DotNetNuke that would do the same thing, but also adds in moderation, versioning, tracking, and more.